Why does having a smaller set of weight help with generalization?
When I studied machine learning for the first time, I learned that we need to use l2 regularization to improve generalization. The reason is based on the polynomial regression experiment in Chris Bishop's textbook, where the author showed the weights of an overfitted polynomial has large weights, which will give incorrect prediction for test data (The argument here is that the large weights will multiply with the data into a large prediction). Regularization will bring the magnitude of the weights down.
However, does this (small weight = better generalization) insight actually generalize beyond the context of polynomial regression? For example, must a neural network with a smaller weights perform better? Even in the context of polynomial regression I'm not so sure. For example, I want to relate millionaire's age with how much they earn. My weight necessarily has to be large. Small weight literally does not make sense here.
The same argument appears in the literature on double descent and implicit regularization. Double descent is said to work because SGD implicitly finds a minimum norm weight in the overparametrized regime. But again the question lingers: why does small set of weight translate into better generalization?
Can anyone chime in on this?

In your example of predicting millionaire earnings based on age, if the output values (earnings) are large, then it might seem that large weights are necessary to represent the relationship accurately. However, in the context of a deep neural network (DNN) by stacking many layers, DNN can represent very complex functions while still maintaining relatively small weights in each layer. And even in traditional models, it might be possible to normalize or rescale the output data so that the target values are in a more manageable range (e.g., between 0 and 1 or within a few standard deviations) which can prevent weights from becoming large while still captures the underlying relationships.
Generally speaking smaller weights tend to be less sensitive to small changes in input which can improve robustness to slight variations and noise in the input data. This makes the model's predictions more reliable and generalizable as small changes in the input won't lead to drastic changes in the output. And as you claimed neural networks trained with small weights are already implicitly regularized by SGD which can reduce the complexity of the functions they learn thus help generalization due to implicit regularization.
